# Send sentence using setRequestProperty

Tags: java, php, android

I am sending image and some text from my Android app to PHP server and I am using this code to do it:

```
            ...
            URL url = new URL("http://example.com/upload.php");

            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("File", imagePath);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty ("Text", someText);
            ...
```

This works when `someText` variable is a word, but when it's a sentence with spaces between words it doesn't work.

Why is that? And is there a way to make it work?

Comment: I think it's preferable to use `Android Volley` for this.

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Comment: `httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty ("Text", "some Text With Spaces");` can you try this?

Comment: Your code segment is not very informative. You have chosen "multipart/form-data;boundary=" but you are not showing how you are setting the datastream with the boundaries. You need to show the rest of your code.